# Autofill across and above a dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, autofill, across

I'd like to autofill cells across and above a dynamic range.

I have a line of numbers in row 3 and would like to put the word "Customer No." in the cell above each one.

[image]

I do this by copying A2 and pasting into C2 then dragging across

[image]

Via VBA macro recorder the code I get looks like this

```
Selection.Copy
Range("C2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:E2"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("C2:E2").Select
```

I was wondering if there's a way to create an autofill across a dynamic range as the number of cells in row 3 will change from time to time?

Thanks

Comment: An alternative solution would be Conditional Formatting.

Comment: Thanks Sam, what functionality in Conditional Formatting could I use exactly?

Comment: Build the condition based on if the cell is empty. If true, make the text white.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```vb
With ActiveSheet
    .Range("C3", .Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Offset(-1).Value = .Range("A2").Value
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however, when I use this code the word "Customer No." goes into the cell A1 and it fills the first three cells across, regardless of how many cells there are in row 2.

Comment: My mistake - typo `2` instead of `3`